# how to flatten complex nested json in spark dataframe using java dynamically

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

My input json dataframe file looks like the following:

```
company: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- county: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- latitude: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- line1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- line2: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- longitude: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- postalCode: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- state: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- code: int (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- stateOtherDescription: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- addressSourceOther: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- addressSourceType: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |     |-- code: int (nullable = true)
|    |    |     |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- reasons: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |     |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |     |-- improve: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |     |-- far: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |     |-- home: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to flatten it dynamically using spark java. Can someone help me with this

Comment: I think your question is not related to apache-spark. How shall the output look like?

Comment: i am receiving data in HDFS and reading in spark df( version 2.3). Output should be all attributes in individual column without nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the de.stefanfrings/parsing/JsonSlurper class in http://stefanfrings.de/bfUtilities/bfUtilities.zip. It reads a JSON document and creates a flat HashMap from the content.